# Genre of songs by Skillet, Imagine Dragons and Simon Curtis

Tags: identify-this-genre

Is there anybody who can tell me what type of music these songs have?

[Skillet - *One Day Too Late*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QXw3i7g2n2U)

[Skillet - *Monsters*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mjlM_RnsVE)

[Simon Curtis - *Super Psycho Love*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHc_j2roK1s)

[Imagine Dragons - *Ready Aim Fire*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOSYr0jM-aY)

[OneRepublic - *Secrets*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qHm9MG9xw1o)

These songs are pretty fast (but not exactly rap) and contain less repeated sentences as compared to many other songs and also have good motivational kind of music but music rarely found alone here. Every time, music is being played behind the song and the singer is singing almost throughout the song.

Are the genre of these songs same? If yes then what is it?

Comment: I concur with both Angst and Ryan.  While Skillet usually gets lumped in with Christian Rock, if you took the Christian element out of it they're really Rock.  Frankly, I find it so difficult to differentiate between certain sub-genres, I just don't recognize them.  Even after reading the Wiki on Alternative and Indie, I can't tell the difference so I'll just use Rock.  And really, as long as it helps **you** distinguish the difference, that's all you need to know.  No need to force bands into ridiculous boxes. I mean, Math Rock is Progressive Rock.  That's it.

Comment: Skillet is Christian Rock (exactly) , alternative rock and Imagine Dragon is alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that they're not the same genre, but they have things in common : 
(mostly) uplifting melody, sung quite high, and as you say, fast-paced, and non-repetitive words.

Except for the Simon Curtis track, other websites (wikipedia etc) tag Skillet, Imagine Dragons and One Republic with several genres, but one in common "alternative rock".  For me "alternative rock" is "rock with a twist" - some different element to standard rock.

All the songs have something which makes them stand out as different - all the things above, which I guess are the things you like about them.  Not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but it'll get things started.

Answer (score 2):

I would class them as indie music, even though they are similar the tracks probably fall into more than one genre with Skillet being more Christian Rock and One Republic being more indie rock.